# Validators message in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, message, validation

In Rails 3, the validators is changed: now is possible to specify all the validators for a specific field in once:

so instead to write
**Rails 2.x.x style**
    `validates_size_of :username, :within => 5..15, :message=> "username size must be between` 5 and 15"

now I can write
   
 **Rails 3 style**

```
 validates :username,  :length => { :minimum => 5, :maximum => 40 }
```

But if I add :messge=> "bla bla bla" in this last example (Rails 3 style) an error occur, so the question is:
How to edit personal error message to the model in order to show them in the view ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you use the shorthand `validates :model` method you can only add specific messages within the context of a specific validator. Example:

```
validates :username, :length => { :minimum => 5, :maximum => 40, :message => 'should be between 5 and 40 characters' }
```

Note that the message is in the hash for the `:length` key. Otherwise Rails doesn't know which validator the message should be applied to.

Comment: And what about the syntax errors.add ? How can I add a specific error from the model ? is it an equivalent tecnique with the one you cited ?

Comment: Can you give me a simple example to use errors.add instead that :message in your code ? Thank you very much

Comment: If you want to add a custom error message, you can still use :message but call a method to generate the error message instead of having a literal string.  Otherwise you can code a totally custom set of validation logic including custom logic to generate your error message. This blog post has examples. http://thelucid.com/2010/01/08/sexy-validation-in-edge-rails-rails-3/